# Find All Elements Given Namespaced Attribute

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

If I have something like this:

```
<p>blah</p>
<p foo:bar="something">blah</p>
<p foo:xxx="something">blah</p>
```

How would I get beautifulsoup to select elements with an attribute of the foo namespace?

E.g. I would like the 2nd and 3rd p elements returned.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#arg-attrs):

Beautiful Soup provides a special argument called attrs which you can use in these situations. attrs is a dictionary that acts just like the keyword arguments:

```
soup.findAll(id=re.compile("para$"))
# [<p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>,
#  <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>]

soup.findAll(attrs={'id' : re.compile("para$")})
# [<p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>,
#  <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>]
```

You can use attrs if you need to put restrictions on attributes whose names are Python reserved words, like class, for, or import; or attributes whose names are non-keyword arguments to the Beautiful Soup search methods: name, recursive, limit, text, or attrs itself.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
xml = '<person name="Bob"><parent rel="mother" name="Alice">'
xmlSoup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)

xmlSoup.findAll(name="Alice")
# []

xmlSoup.findAll(attrs={"name" : "Alice"})
# [parent rel="mother" name="Alice"></parent>]
```

---

So for your given example:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={ "foo" : re.compile(".*") })
# or
soup.findAll(attrs={ re.compile("foo:.*") : re.compile(".*") })
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup (both version 3 and 4) does not appear to treat the namespace-prefix as anything special. It just treats tho namespace-prefix and namespaced attribute as an attribute that happens to have a colon in its name.

So to find as `<p>` elements with attributes in the `foo` namespace, you just have to loop through all the attribute keys and check if `attr.startswith('foo')`:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
content = '''\
<p>blah</p>
<p foo:bar="something">blah</p>
<p foo:xxx="something">blah</p>'''

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    for attr in p.attrs.keys():
        if attr.startswith('foo'):
            print(p)
            break
```

yields

```
<p foo:bar="something">blah</p>
<p foo:xxx="something">blah</p>
```

---

With [lxml](http://lxml.de/) you can search by XPath, which does have syntax support for searching for attributes by namespace:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
content = '''\
<root xmlns:foo="bar">
<p>blah</p>
<p foo:bar="something">blah</p>
<p foo:xxx="something">blah</p></root>'''

root = ET.XML(content)
for p in root.xpath('p[@foo:*]', namespaces={'foo':'bar'}):
    print(ET.tostring(p))
```

yields

```
<p xmlns:foo="bar" foo:bar="something">blah</p>
<p xmlns:foo="bar" foo:xxx="something">blah</p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to match the start of an attribute so any attribute that begins with foo:? I've edited by question.