# How to use an attribute that has colon in ite name

Tags: python, attributes

When an object attribute has colon in its name, how to use the attribute? The code where I came across this situation is :

```
instances = nova.servers.list()
for i in instances:
        print i.id, i.OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname
```

After looking at the link [Find All Elements Given Namespaced Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243858/find-all-elements-given-namespaced-attribute) and [How do I escape a colon in Python format() when using kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913504/how-do-i-escape-a-colon-in-python-format-when-using-kwargs)
I tried using attr as

```
instances = nova.servers.list()
for i in instances:
        print i.id, i.(attr={"OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR":"hypervisor_hostname"})
```

But it gives error as Invalid syntax. How should I use the attribute OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname

Comment: How were you able to __set__ an attribute with such a name?

Comment: I am intrigued as to why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use objects with attributes with such names. Use a dict.

It's possible to set and get attributes with invalid Python names:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 

>>> class A():
...     pass
... 

>>> a = A()

>>> setattr(a, 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'some_string')

>>> a.OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname
  File "<ipython-input-5-849986a021bc>", line 1
    a.OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


>>> getattr(a, 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname')
>>> 'some_string'

>>>
```

But don't do this, use a dict to store this info, not object's attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used dict.

Answer (score 0):

With [setattr(object, name, value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)) and read it with [getattr(object, name[, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)¶

see also
[How do you programmatically set an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute)

Why do you want to do this? I found myself in a situation where I needed wrap an AWS Cognito user fields within my own class rather than a dict.

```
        for attr in admin_get_user_dict['UserAttributes']:
            setattr(cognito_user, attr['Name'], attr['Value'])
```

In Cognito, custom attributes are prefixed by **custom:**[your_attr_name] so there you have it. And yes, you want to avoid this at any cost if you are designing your own classes.